# Download files from Google Presentations

Tags: google-drive, download, google-slides

I am working with Google Presentations with my students. I'd like to offer them the option to download other documents (Excel, PDF, etc) from my Google Drive connected with my Presentations, using a link in the text in my presentation. How can I do this? So students using my presentation should be able to download a slide or a PDF or just anything.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to have the files (to be linked to) already on your Google Drive. Right click on the file you want to link to, and select Share, Share. The link for the file is displayed so all you need to do is copy and paste the link in the appropriate spot.

Comment: You can also use Google's url shortener (http://goo.gl/) to optimize those links (they're big).